# Power BI Measure: Aggregate By, Filter By, Group By, Simple Math

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am attempting to make a measure that calculates:

SUM(Num_Compliant) / SUM(Num_Asked) for a District, filtered to the current Fiscal Year (i.e. Date on or after 07/01/2018, or July 1, 2018).

```
District    Date        Section   Num_Compliant  Num_Asked
A           11/12/2018  I         3              8
A           1/12/2018   I         3              8
A           11/17/2018  II        1              6
A           5/18/2018   II        3              6
B           2/20/2019   I         4              8
B           4/20/2018   I         5              8
B           11/12/2018  II        6              6
B           1/12/2018   II        1              6
C           11/17/2018  I         2              8
C           5/18/2018   I         3              8
C           4/20/2018   II        5              6
```

With the above sample data, I expect the following results

```
District    Numerator   Denominator Value
A           4           14          0.29
B           10          14          0.71
C           2           8           0.25
```

I intentionally made the denominator different in district C to reflect the fact that sections are sometimes missing.

I have been trying to solve this for about a day, and am brand-new to Power BI, so I apologize if this is a very simple question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following measure looks like it solves your needs:

```
Value = 
var __date = DATE(2018,7,1)
var __Numerator = CALCULATE(sum(Compliancy[Num_Compliant]),ALLEXCEPT(Compliancy,Compliancy[Distict]),Compliancy[Date]>__date)
var __Denominator = CALCULATE(sum(Compliancy[Num_asked]),ALLEXCEPT(Compliancy,Compliancy[Distict]),Compliancy[Date]>__date)

return __Numerator/__Denominator
```

Please note you will have to change "Compliancy" to your table name throughout the DAX formula. Also, the date is currently hard coded into the DAX, it might be best to use a date slicer so you can change the values on the fly. The measure without the date filter hard coded as is as follows:

```
Value = 
var __Numerator = CALCULATE(sum(Compliancy[Num_Compliant]),ALLEXCEPT(Compliancy,Compliancy[Distict]))
var __Denominator = CALCULATE(sum(Compliancy[Num_asked]),ALLEXCEPT(Compliancy,Compliancy[Distict]))

return __Numerator/__Denominator
```

Table in Power BI:

[image: Power BI Table]

As a side note of things to watch out for:

- The measure "Value" needs to be set to the format "Decimal Place"
  with 2 decimals.
- The date field must be appropriately set to the
  "Date" data type.